# Get data with AJAX call and templify them with Mustache

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mustache

I'm trying to templify data from an AJAX call on the client side. The data is present in the `data` argument in the `success` function, but somehow it doesn't 'see' it. It's not displaying the data that should be placed in the template.

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public object SetFilters(dynamic param)
{
     var t = _servrep.GetAvailableServices(param.filters);
     return Enumerable.Select(t,(Func<dynamic, dynamic>) 
                   (x => new { x.Name, x.Comments }));
 }
```

This is the success function of the AJAX call:

```
success: function (data) 
{
    //debugger;
    //var sdata = JSON.stringify(data);
    var template = $('#serviceTemplate').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('#servicePlaceholder').html(html);
},
```

When I uncomment the `debugger` statement in the `success` function, the `data` looks like this: `[[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]]`

When I expand it, I do see the key value pairs `Name` and `Comments` with a value.

What am I missing?

[EDIT]

```
<script id="serviceTemplate" type="text/template">
    <li>
        <h4>{{Name}}</h4>
        <div>
            {{Comments}}

        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an array of objects.  Maybe try indexing your data before passing it to Mustache.

```
 var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data[0]);
```

Or you can try looping through each one.  I'm not too familiar with the mustache syntax but it should look something like this

```
//JS
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, {data: data});

//template

{{#data}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <p>{{comments}}</p>
{{/data}}
```

Comment: Hi, that data[0] worked, but only for the first one in the array. So I tried your `each` approach but that didn't display anything. I've got to say that my template is defined outside the AJAX call. See my original post edited to show you what I mean.

Comment: I looked up the mustache syntax, try doing it without the each keyword.  Updated example.  https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists